# Spring HandlerInterceptor is not capturing methods other than GET, POST

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

My goal is not to allow `OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE` HTTP methods as advised by security testing.

**INTRO**

I have a spring application. I do have spring security embedded in it.

**TRY-1**

I tried to add `<security-constraint>` in  web.xml ref - http://www.techstacks.com/howto/disable-http-methods-in-tomcat.html

This is working but it provides invalid Response header.

RESPONSE

```
> Status : 403
> Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
```

As mentioned, the Allow response header shouldn't be returned.

**TRY-2**

So I tried to add `HandlerInterceptor`

```
public class HTTPMethodInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor  {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
         if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("options") ||
                 request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("put")||
                 request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
             response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Unauthorized Request");
             return false;
         }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest arg0,
            HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, Exception arg3)
            throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1,
            Object arg2, ModelAndView arg3) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

EDIT

Registered it in springConfig by

```
<mvc:interceptors>
  <bean class="com.HTTPMethodInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

This preHandle is working for "GET" and "POST" method. But it is not working for rest of the method.

Correct me, if my understanding is wrong. Pardon me if it is duplicate.

Comment: Do you need it for all requests, or just certain URLs? How do you register this `HandlerInterceptor` to Spring context?

Comment: @luboskrnac I need it for all URL. `/*` would be great. Edited question for register

Answer (score 0):

I used `CSRF` request matcher to do this trick and it is working great.

Created a request matcher as follows

```
 public class SecurityRequestMatcher implements org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher {
 public static final String OPTIONS = "options";
 public static final String DELETE = "delete";
 public static final String PUT = "PUT";

    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
         if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(OPTIONS) ||
                 request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(DELETE)||
                 request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(PUT)) {
             return true;
         }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Spring config as

```
<bean id="securityRequestMatcher"
      class="com.SecurityRequestMatcher"/>
<security:http>
<security:csrf request-matcher-ref="securityRequestMatcher"/>
</security:http>
```

And bingo :D